# How can i retrieve this data?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, webi

I have two dimensions, login and username containing names of people who have an account, and who have actually logged in to their account respectively. How do i retrieve the names that are in login but absent in username? I am using Webi Rich Client XI 3.1

[image]

Comment: Kamal, does Webi Rich Client allow you to write a SQL statement for this, or do you have to create your report through a web interface of some sort?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest merging your **User Name** and **Login** dimensions.  You will then need to create detail variables for User Name and Login with your newly merged dimension as the associated dimension as described in *Tip 1* of this blog post...

http://michaelwelter.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/tips-for-merging-dimensions/

You can then put them both on the report as part of the same table and put a filter where User Name is null.

Here is another blog post which has a lot of information about merged dimensions.

http://www.dagira.com/2010/06/19/what-does-extend-merged-dimensions-really-do/

My company is on 4.0 SP06.  I have never used XI 3.1, but I think this (or something very similar) should work.

Noel